# backspace not working during validation in firefox

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox

I have written the below code so that users only enter numbers. It works fine in all the browsers excepts FireFox

In FireFox after entering a number if the users clicks backspace it is not working properly. Below is the code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getKeyCodeFromEvent(e) {
            if (typeof e == "object" && typeof e.which == "number") {
                return e.which;
            }
            return window.event.keyCode;
        }

        function checkEntry(e) {
            var keyCode = this.getKeyCodeFromEvent(e);
            var regularExpression = /^[0-9.]+$/;
            return regularExpression.test(String.fromCharCode(keyCode));
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" onkeypress="return checkEntry(event);" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you checking for the backspace (8) or the delete (46) keycode? And the arrow keys as well. It might almost be easier to just validate the input afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

When someone presses the backspace key, you get the value `8` from `getKeyCodeFromEvent`. Running it in `String.fromCharCode(8);` then returns the following unicode value: ``. This does not match your regex, so it fails.

You could solve this by checking that the backspace, delete, tab, left and right keys are allowed, before turning them into String values. You will need to use the `keydown` event though, because `keypress` does not return values for certain keys, such as left or right.

Be careful when restricting user movement like this though, as it might easily make people angry, when the site doesn't work as they expect it to.

```
<script>

    function getKeyCodeFromEvent(e) {
        if (typeof e == "object" && typeof e.which == "number") {
            return e.which;
        }
        return window.event.keyCode;
    }

    function checkEntry(e) {

        var keyCode = getKeyCodeFromEvent(e);
        var regularExpression = /^[0-9.]+$/;

        // If the key is backspace, tab, left, right or delete
        if([8,9,37,39,46].indexOf(keyCode) !== -1 || e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
            return true;
        }
        if(!regularExpression.test(String.fromCharCode(keyCode))) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }
    }

    // I took the liberty of moving your event from the HTML into JavaScript, where it belongs
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        document.getElementById('numberinput').addEventListener("keydown", checkEntry, false);
    }, false);
</script>
<input type="text" id="numberinput" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8hzwLjfz/6/

Comment: i realized in firefox it does not allow me to click right, left.. arrows also, Also if ctrl+a combination also does not work, Is there any way to achieve this also

Comment: Updated it to allow for ctrl and cmd key commands on mac as well. I'm really not sure if this is a very good idea to begin with...